# Running total in SQLite in select

Tags: sqlite

I have been searching the web for past 4 days about how to get running total in SQLite through a select statement.... but in vain... I was using view and it worked perfectly fine for SQLite version 1.0.74.0.. but after updating it to version 1.0.105.2.. it has stopped working. I have tried everything but its not perfect...
For example

---

```
rowid | date       | name | debit | credit

  7   | 24.07.2017 | bob  | 792   | 0 

  1   | 25.07.2017 | jon  | 792   | 0

  5   | 25.07.2017 | maggi|  0 | 500
```

Now I want is running total of debit and credit side but its going nowhere

I am using the following query

```
select date,
name,DEBIT,CREDIT,
(select SUM(cashwithdraw)-SUM(cashdeposit) from _temp as a where a.rowid<=b.rowid )+0.0 AS balance,
from _temp as b order by date
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output.

Comment: Sample data i have provided in the question and desired output is running total of both fields debit and credit

Answer (score 0):

I have Found the Answer to my question ..though it required a lost of searching,here goes

in my post i am trying to get rowid in views which is never possible. so the solution for this problem solved by creating a temporary table say by the name '_temp' now by doing this the rowid column automatically reorganizes itself and the the query works like a charm.

```
select date,
name,DEBIT,CREDIT,
(select SUM(cashwithdraw)-SUM(cashdeposit) from _temp as a where a.rowid<=b.rowid )+0.0 AS balance,
from _temp as b order by date
```